# Part of my bamboo is dying & Small bumps near the branch growing from the node

Tags: lucky-bamboo

I have noticed over the past few months that one of my 3 bamboo stocks is turning brown, but strangely only part of it is brown while there is a small sliver on green that remains. Is there anything i could do to stop this?

I have also noticed that on all of my stocks, in the same place that there have been small tan/brownish bumps that are hard to the touch in the area where the branch connects to the node. What are these bumps? Is it scale or some other disease? Or is it new growth?

[image: Here's some photos of the stock and the bumps]

[image]

[image]

[image]